# How to remove all special characters except spaces and dashes from a Python string?

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I want to strip all special characters from a Python string, except dashes and spaces.

Is this correct?

```
import re
my_string = "Web's GReat thing-ok"
pattern = re.compile('[^A-Za-z0-9 -]')
new_string = pattern.sub('',my_string)
new_string
>> 'Webs GReat thing-ok'
# then make it lowercase and replace spaces with underscores
# new_string = new_string.lower().replace (" ", "_")
# new_string
# >> 'webs_great_thing-ok'
```

As shown, I ultimately want to replace the spaces with underscores after removing the other special characters, but figured I would do it in stages.  Is there a Pythonic way to do it all in one fell swoop?

For context, I am using this input for MongoDB collection names, so want the constraint of the final string to be:  alphanumeric with dashes and underscores allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are actually trying to "slugify" your string.

If you don't mind using a 3rd party (and a Python 2 specific) library you can use `slugify` (`pip install slugify`):

```
import slugify

string = "Web's GReat thing-ok"
print slugify.slugify(string)
>> 'webs_great_thing-ok'
```

You can implement it yourself. 
All of `slugify`'s code is

```
import re
import unicodedata

def slugify(string):
    return re.sub(r'[-\s]+', '-',
            unicode(
                    re.sub(r'[^\w\s-]', '',
                           unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', string)
                           .encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
                           .strip()
                           .lower())
```

Note that this is Python 2 specific.

Going back to your example, You can make it a one-liner. Whether it is Pythonic enough is up to you to decide (note the shortened range `A-z` instead of `A-Za-z`):

```
import re

my_string = "Web's GReat thing-ok"
new_string = re.sub('[^A-z0-9 -]', '', my_string).lower().replace(" ", "_")
```

**UPDATE** There seems to be more robust and Python 3 compatible "slugify" library [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/awesome-slugify/1.6.5).

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner, as requested:

```
>>> import re, unicodedata
>>> value = "Web's GReat thing-ok"
>>> re.sub('[\s]+', '_', re.sub('[^\w\s-]', '', unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', unicode(value)).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')).strip().lower())
u'webs_great_thing-ok'
```